# Generating RSA public key from byte array

Tags: java, rsa, bouncycastle

I am having some trouble generating a RSA public key object. In this method, I read e (exponent) and n (modulus) from a file into two byte arrays. I want to use those two byte arrays to create a RSA public key object. Unfortunately, in my implementation, I get an error saying that the input is too large to encrypt. However, e and n are both 1024 bits and the input is only 32 bytes.

```
private static void send() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    byte[] senderFileBytes = getFileBytes(senderPrivateKeyFile);
    byte[] receiverFileBytes = getFileBytes(receiverPublicKeyFile);
    byte[] plainTextFileBytes = getFileBytes(plainTextFile);
    byte[] senderPrivateKeyBytes = new byte[128];
    byte[] senderModulusBytes = new byte[128];
    byte[] receiverPublicKeyBytes = new byte[128];
    byte[] receiverModulusBytes = new byte[128];

    System.arraycopy(senderFileBytes, 0, senderModulusBytes, 0, 128);
    System.arraycopy(senderFileBytes, 128, senderPrivateKeyBytes, 0, 128);
    System.arraycopy(receiverFileBytes, 0, receiverModulusBytes, 0, 128);
    System.arraycopy(receiverFileBytes, 128, receiverPublicKeyBytes, 0, 128);

    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] aesKeyBytes = new byte[16];
    byte[] ivKeyBytes = new byte[16];
    random.nextBytes(aesKeyBytes); //These two are being concatenated 
    random.nextBytes(ivKeyBytes);  //And then encrypted with RSA

    //Relevant section
    BigInteger receiverPublicKeyInteger = new BigInteger(receiverPublicKeyBytes);
    BigInteger receiverModulusInteger = new BigInteger(receiverModulusBytes);
    RSAPublicKeySpec receiverPublicKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(receiverModulusInteger, receiverPublicKeyInteger);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
    RSAPublicKey receiverPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(receiverPublicKeySpec);

    Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/NoPadding", "BC");
    rsaCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, receiverPublicKey);
    byte[] aesIvBytes = concat(aesKeyBytes, ivKeyBytes);
    byte[] sessionCipher = rsaCipher.doFinal(aesIvBytes); //Error here

}
```

I've tested the BigInteger using `intValue()` and they seem to be correct.  For instance, `receiverPublicKeyInteger`'s value is 65537 which is the value I inputted in the file. I think the error might be how I created the key.

Comment: I think I found the problem. Apparently BigInteger(byte[] array) is interpreted as two's complements form. Thus my modulus is a negative number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this issue. The issue was because the `BigInteger(byte[] array)` constructor reads `array` in two's complement form. Because modulus byte array is not to be interpreted in two's complements form, using the above constructor can yield a negative integer.

Therefore, using this constructor solves the problem `BigInteger(int signum, byte[] array)`.

Comment: to any potential reader, signum is 1 for positive and -1 for negative numbers